# Capturing Audio With Screen Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screen, html5-audio

in chrome extension i used following line to capture the screen

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia
```

by this screen (Desktop) stream is working fine, however when I tried to capture the audio using

```
constraints = {
   audio: {
     mandatory: {
       chromeMediaSource: 'system',
       chromeMediaSourceId: audioSource,
     }
   },
   video: {
     mandatory: {
       chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
       chromeMediaSourceId: event.data.sourceId,
       maxWidth: window.screen.width,
       maxHeight: window.screen.height,
       maxFrameRate: 3
     },
     optional: [
       { googLeakyBucket: true },
       { googTemporalLayeredScreencast: true }
     ]
   }
 };
```

Note: already tested `event.data.sourceId` in place of `audioSource` in audio block.

Audio is not working, I can see (in console) audio media track from stream

Same feature is working in [this app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by adding `'audio'` in the `dataSources` array passed into `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia`.

i.e. `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['screen', 'audio'], function(id) {...});`

Answer (score -1):

The extension you are referring to uses platform-specific code (ffmpeg) as a binary located into _platform_specific/x86-64/video_encoder_main-x86-64.nexe and not WebRTC/HTML5

[edit] the above is on Linux 64 bits

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not true. The binary you refer to is an (efficient) encoder - however, seeing how heavily sandboxed NaCl is I doubt it can access screen/audio capture. And the source does refer to WebRTC.

Comment: Guys did you find a answer to this question? Unable to make audio work.